# ContentProvider for multiple databases/ContentProviders

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, searchview

Can anyone tell how can I create a ContentProvider which can query multiple database/ContentProviders for search suggestions provided by SearchView.

Answer (score 2):

With ContentProviders, you are querying for data using a ContentUrl which would look something like this

```
content://<authority>/<data_type>/<id>
```

**authority** is the content provider name, e.g. contacts or for custom one will be com.xxxxx.yyy.

**data_type** and **id** are to specify what data you need from the provide and, if needed, a specific value for the key.

So, if you are building your custom content provider you need to parse the content uri which you get as a parameter in the query function and decide what data you need to return as Cursor. UriMatcher class is very good choice for this case. Here is an example

```
static final String URL = "content://com.mycompany.myapp/students";
static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse(URL);

static final UriMatcher uriMatcher;
static{
  uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
  uriMatcher.addURI("com.mycompany.myapp", "students", 1);
  uriMatcher.addURI("com.mycompany.myapp", "students/#", 2);
}
```

then in your query function, you would have something like this:

```
switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
  case 1:
     // we are querying for all students
     // return a cursor all students e.g. "SELECT * FROM students"
     break;
  case 2:
     // we are querying for all students
     // return a cursor for the student matching the given id (the last portion of uri)
     // e.g. "SELECT * FROM students WHERE _id = n"
     break;
  default:
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
  }
```

I hope this answers your question and direct you to the right track.

You can see a good article with full example about how to use them, here 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_content_providers.htm